Keeping matching elements in their place while sorting an array
I’m trying to sort an array of 6 integers in descending order in javascript but keep matching values in their place as the other values are sorted.
An example is posted below to help explain this problem:
Input: 4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3
Output: 4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2

Another Example with multiple matching values:
Input: 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 8
Output: 3, 4, 3, 4, 8, 2

If there is no matching values:
Input:
6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 4
Output:
9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2

First you would need to check whether if any values values match, and which values match. I’m not exactly sure how to do this in this context. I’m also not sure how to sort all the other values in the array other than the matching ones. Thanks in advance!
I tried running a for loop for the length of the array that checks every number to see whether there are any matches but this caused repeated values and doesn’t get any closer to the solution.

Use Javscript's Array.prototype.sort function. It makes sorting alot easier.
The callback gets passed two values, a and b, that need to be compared. The number you return decides where the values need to go:

a negative value means that a should come before b
a positive value means that a should come after b
0 or NaN means that a and b are considered equal.


Note: Array.prototype.sort() modifies the current arry. To create a new array, use toSorted()

Here is a simple example that sorts an array the way you needed using Array.prototype.sort. Hopefully it's not too confusing ;)


// function to sort in descending order,
// used with Array.prototype.sort()
function sortDescending(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}

function sort(values) {
    let matchingNumbers = [] // all matching numbers go in here

    // to find matches, keep a list of all previous
    // numbers as you iterate over the array. If
    // the the list of previous numbers contains the same
    // number, then there is a match.
    let previousNumbers = []
    values.forEach(function(val) {
        if (previousNumbers.includes(val)) {
            
            // there is a match, so push it to 
            // matchingNumbers if it has not been
            // encountered yet
            if (!matchingNumbers.includes(val)) {
                matchingNumbers.push(val)
            }
        }

        // add this value to previous values
        previousNumbers.push(val)
    })

    // now, create a list of non-matching numbers
    let individuals = [];

    // and fill it
    values.forEach(function(val) {
        if (!matchingNumbers.includes(val)) {
            
            // this isn't a match, so put it in
            // the non-matches list
            individuals.push(val)
        }
    })

    // now sort the non-matches
    // using Array.prototype.sort
    let sortedIndividuals = individuals.toSorted(sortDescending) // largest to smallest

    // make an array for the result
    let result = values.slice() // .slice() with no params returns duplicate aray

    // now lop through values and for each
    // non-match, fill it with the correct
    // sorted individual number
    values.forEach(function(val, indx) {
    let i = individuals.indexOf(val) // index of individual
        if (i != -1) { // if val is an individual

            // replace the result at this spot
            // with the correct sorted individual
            result[indx] = sortedIndividuals[i]
        }
    })

    return result
}

function demo() {
    let test = Array.from({ length: 6 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    
    console.log("original", JSON.stringify(test))
    console.log("sorted", JSON.stringify(sort(test)))
}
<button onclick="demo()">Demo</button>



The algorithm I'm using here is basically just getting a list of all the non-matches, sorting them, and putting them back in the right spots. If you read the code you should get how it works.

I think you missed the part where it's supposed to keep the duplicated values in the same position.

@NickParsons Oops, I fixed that

You can try to:

Create an array of unique values from your original array (unique)
Create a set of values that appear multiple times (dups)
Sort the unique values in descending order
Loop through your original array, "replacing" each value at each index with the one from the sorted array if it's not duplicated.



function sortUnique(arr) {
  const grouped = Map.groupBy(arr, n => n);
  const dups = new Set();
  const unique = [];

  for (const [n, grp] of grouped)
    if (grp.length > 1) dups.add(n);
    else unique.push(n);

  const sorted = unique.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  const output = [];
  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (dups.has(arr[i])) output.push(arr[i]); 
    else output.push(sorted[j++]);
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(sortUnique([4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3]));
console.log(sortUnique([3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 8]));
console.log(sortUnique([6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 4]));




Is there something wrong with my answer?

You need to first generate a frequency map. This will let you know if there are any duplicates.
Once you have a frequency map, you can grab all the unique values and sort them in descending order.
As for the duplicates, you can store their index along with their value in a matrix (list of pairs) to determine splice order.
I tried my best to keep this as functional as possible. Each function performs the minimal amount of effort to achieve its purpose.
Note: I used the Mocha/Chai test framework to validate all your given test cases.


const { expect } = chai;

const testCases = [
  // Has duplicates
  { label: 'A', data: [4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3], expected: [4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] },
  { label: 'B', data: [3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 8], expected: [3, 4, 3, 4, 8, 2] },
  // No duplicates
  { label: 'C', data: [6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 4], expected: [9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] }
];

const main = () => {
  mocha.setup('bdd');
  mocha.checkLeaks();

  describe('Mocha + Chai', function() {
    for (let { data, expected, label } of testCases) {
      it(`Test case ${label}`, function() {
        const actual = keepDupeFixedSort(data);
        expect(actual).to.deep.equal(expected);
      });
    }
  });

  mocha.run();
};

// This is the function we want to test
const keepDupeFixedSort = (data) => {
  const frequencyMap = getFrequencyMap(data);
  const sortedUnique = toUniqueSortedDesc(data, frequencyMap);
  const pairs = dupeIndices(data, frequencyMap);
  return spliceAll(sortedUnique, pairs);
};

const getFrequencyMap = (data) => data.reduce((acc, v) =>
  acc.set(v, (acc.get(v) ?? 0) + 1), new Map());

const toUniqueSortedDesc = (data, frequencyMap) =>
  data.filter(v => frequencyMap.get(v) === 1)
    .toSorted((a, b) => b - a);

const dupeIndices = (data, frequencyMap) =>
  data.reduce((arr, v, index) =>
    frequencyMap.get(v) > 1 ? [...arr, [index, v]] : arr, []);

const spliceAll = (data, indexValuePairs) => {
  const result = [...data];
  for (let [index, value] of indexValuePairs) {
    result.splice(index, 0, value);
  }
  return result;
};

main(); // Call the test suite
<link href="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script src="http://chaijs.com/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.js"></script>



Alternatively, spliceAll could be defined functionally as:
const spliceAll = (data, indexValuePairs) =>
  indexValuePairs.reduce((acc, [index, value]) =>
    acc.toSpliced(index, 0, value), data);


Update
Here is a more efficient; imperative approach:


const { expect } = chai;

const testCases = [
  // Has duplicates
  { label: 'A', data: [4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3], expected: [4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] },
  { label: 'B', data: [3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 8], expected: [3, 4, 3, 4, 8, 2] },
  // No duplicates
  { label: 'C', data: [6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 4], expected: [9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] }
];

const main = () => {
  mocha.setup('bdd');
  mocha.checkLeaks();

  describe('Mocha + Chai', function() {
    for (let { data, expected, label } of testCases) {
      it(`Test case ${label}`, function() {
        const actual = keepDupeFixedSort(data);
        expect(actual).to.deep.equal(expected);
      });
    }
  });

  mocha.run();
};

// This is the function we want to test
const keepDupeFixedSort = (data) => {
  const frequencyMap = getFrequencyMap(data);
  const { uniqueValues, duplicates } = categorizeValues(data, frequencyMap);
  return mergeUniqueAndDuplicates(uniqueValues, duplicates, data.length);
};

const getFrequencyMap = (data) =>
  data.reduce((acc, val) =>
    updateMapValue(acc, val, v => v + 1, 0), new Map());

const updateMapValue = (map, key, updateFn, initialValue) =>
  map.set(key, updateFn(map.get(key) ?? initialValue));

const categorizeValues = (data, frequencyMap) => {
  const uniqueValues = [], duplicates = [];
  data.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (frequencyMap.get(value) === 1) {
      uniqueValues.push(value);
    } else {
      duplicates.push([index, value]);
    }
  });
  return { uniqueValues, duplicates };
};

const mergeUniqueAndDuplicates = (uniqueValues, duplicates, length) => {
  const result = Array(length).fill(null);
  let uniqueIndex = 0;
  // Insert duplicates back into their original positions
  for (const [index, value] of duplicates) {
    result[index] = value;
  }
  // Fill any remaining gaps with sorted unique values
  uniqueValues.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i] === null) {
      result[i] = uniqueValues[uniqueIndex++];
    }
  }
  return result;
};

main(); // Call the test suite
.as-console-wrapper { color: black; }
<link href="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script src="http://chaijs.com/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.js"></script>




You could use 2 maps to collect values and indices in 1 go to sort and push back to the original array:


const tests = [
  [4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3],
  [3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 8],
  [6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 4]
];

function sortUniqueValues(arr, inplace = false){
  
  const found = new Map, indices = new Map;
  
  arr.forEach((v, i) => {
    const prevIdx = found.get(v);
    if(prevIdx === undefined) found.set(v, i), indices.set(i, v);
    else indices.delete(prevIdx);
  });

  const result = inplace ? arr : arr.slice();
  const indices2 = [...indices.keys()];
  [...indices.values()].sort((a, b) => b - a).forEach((a, i) => result[indices2[i]] = a);
  return result;
}

tests.forEach(test => console.log(...sortUniqueValues(test)));



Benchmark with Nick's:
` Chrome/125
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                n=10       |       n=100       |      n=1000      |     n=10000     
Alexander   ■ 1.00x x1m 360 | ■ 1.00x x100k 315 | ■ 1.00x x10k 535 | ■ 1.00x x100 101
Nick          1.05x x1m 379 |   1.15x x100k 361 |   1.26x x10k 672 |   1.06x x100 107
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


let $length = 10;
const test = Array.from({length: $length}, () => Math.random() * $length | 0);

function sortUnique(arr) {
  const grouped = Map.groupBy(arr, n => n);
  const dups = new Set();
  const unique = [];

  for (const [n, grp] of grouped)
    if (grp.length > 1) dups.add(n);
    else unique.push(n);

  const sorted = unique.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  const output = [];
  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (dups.has(arr[i])) output.push(arr[i]); 
    else output.push(sorted[j++]);
  }
  return output;
}


function sortUniqueValues(arr, inplace = false){
  
  const found = new Map, indices = new Map;
  
  arr.forEach((v, i) => {
    const prevIdx = found.get(v);
    if(prevIdx === undefined) found.set(v, i), indices.set(i, v);
    else indices.delete(prevIdx);
  });

  const result = inplace ? arr : arr.slice();
  const indices2 = [...indices.keys()];
  [...indices.values()].sort((a, b) => b - a).forEach((a, i) => result[indices2[i]] = a);
  return result;
}

// @benchmark Alexander
sortUniqueValues(test);

// @benchmark Nick
sortUnique(test);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



